# How to use union if i need to "order by" all selects

Tags: sql

i have 3 separate select statements that i need to union. but all of them need to be ordered by a different column. 
i tried doing this

```
select * from(
select * from (select columns from table1 order by column1 ) A
UNION
select * from (select columns from table2 order by column2 ) B
UNION
select * from (select columns from table3 order by column3 ) C
) Table
```

but this doesn't work
does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: do they have the same structure ?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. Can you perhaps provide an example of the data that you've got and the result that you want that might clarify things?

Comment: the queries have the same structure. i am selecting from the same tables. but they have different conditions and need to be ordered by different columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select *
from((select columns, 'table1' as which from table1  )
     UNION ALL
     (select columns, 'table2' from table2 )
     UNION ALL
     (select columns, 'table3' from table3 )
    ) t
order by which,
         (case when which = 'table1' then column1
               when which = 'table2' then column2
               when which = 'table3' then column3
          end);
```

This assumes that the columns used for ordering are all of the same type.

Note that this query uses `union all` instead of `union`.  I see no reason why you would want to eliminate duplicates if you want the results from the three subqueries ordered independently.

EDIT:

You can also express the `order by` separately for each table:

```
order by which,
         (case when which = 'table1' then column1 end) ASC,
         (case when which = 'table2' then column2 end) DESC
         (case when which = 'table3' then column3 end)
```

Comment: this seems to work. thank you. but i also need to add asc and desc. is that possible with this method???

Answer (score 1):

You should separate these columns in the one common column and then order

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT A.*,columnA as ORDER_COL FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.*,columnB as ORDER_COL FROM B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT C.*,columnC as ORDER_COL FROM C
) as T1 
ORDER BY ORDER_COL
```

Comment: how can i add asc and desc to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to order it AFTER the UNION's.

You can "trick it" like this:

```
select Artificial, a,b,c from(
select 1 as Artificial, a,b,c from (select columns from table1  ) A
UNION
select 2 as Artificial,a,b,c from (select columns from table2  ) B
UNION
select 3 as Artificial,a,b,c from (select columns from table3  ) C
) derivedTable

order by Artificial, c,b,a
```